# Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Runs but Awaits was expected

Tags: kotlin, mockk, kotest

I am currently writing tests using kotest and MockK in Kotlin.
I encountered an error during the mocking process while writing tests in Kotlin using kotest and MockK.

```
every { accountService.findAccount(nonExistAccountId.toString()) } just Runs
//Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Runs but Awaits was expected
```

But previously, I didn't encounter any problems with the same process.

```
every { noticeRepository.delete(any()) } just  Runs
//no error
```

So, I checked the declaration of 'just'.

```
/**
 * Part of DSL. Answer placeholder for Unit returning functions.
 */
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
infix fun MockKStubScope<Unit, Unit>.just(runs: Runs) = answers(ConstantAnswer(Unit))

/**
 * Part of DSL. Answer placeholder for never returning suspend functions.
 */
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
infix fun <T, B> MockKStubScope<T, B>.just(awaits: Awaits) = coAnswers { awaitCancellation() }
```

Why isn't the function above being called?

Comment: `findAccount` is supposed to return a something. It can't "just runs". What do you want it to return?

Comment: @Sweeper Ah, thank you. I see, if something is being returned, 'Runs' cannot be used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you don't have an error in this case because the `delete()` method in  `noticeRepository` returns `Unit`.

```
every { noticeRepository.delete(any()) } just  Runs
```

`just  Runs` is only used to mock responses of functions or methods that return `Unit`

When you want to mock response for method that actually DOES returns a values, you use different approach

```
every { accountService.findAccount(nonExistAccountId.toString()) } returns // add your Account mock value here
```

More details can be found here: https://mockk.io/#answers